# vue js - radio button won't check by default with v-model attribute

Tags: javascript, radio-button, vue.js, checked

If I remove the `v-model` attribute, `checked` works.

```
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="+" v-model="sumType" checked="checked"> Addition
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="-" v-model="sumType"> Subtraction
```

How do I default check a radio button that has a vue js model attribute?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the `v-model` property to the value of the radio that you want to be checked by default.

For example:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sumType: '-'
    }
  }
}
```

would select the `Subtraction` radio on page load.

Using the following HTML (with the above component structure) works:

```
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="+" v-model="sumType"> Addition
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="-" v-model="sumType"> Subtraction
```

Answer (score 2):

`sumType` model's value overrides your `checked` attribute.

Probably, you want to specify the binding value (`v-bind:value=""`):

```
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="+" v-bind:value="+" v-model="sumType"> Addition
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="-" v-bind:value="-" v-model="sumType"> Subtraction
```

Comment: May be, '+' should be wrapped with strings, `v-bind:value=" '+' "` rather just `v-bind:value="+"`